# Detecting whether airplay devices are available

Tags: ios, swift, airplay

I'd like to display the Airplay icon in an iPhone app as an `UIBarButtonItem` only when airplay devices (other than the user's iPhone) are available.

```
var volumeView = MPVolumeView!
```

I've set up the `UIBarButtonItem` in the `viewDidLoad()` like that:

```
volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 0.0, height: 0.0))
volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = false
let airplayBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: volumeView)
if let routeButton = volumeView.subviews.last as? UIButton,
  let routeButtonTemplateImage = routeButton.currentImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) {
  volumeView.setRouteButtonImage(routeButtonTemplateImage, for: .normal)
  volumeView.tintColor = myColor
}

volumeView.showsRouteButton = volumeView.areWirelessRoutesAvailable
```

In the `viewWillAppear()`:

```
volumeView.showsRouteButton = volumeView.areWirelessRoutesAvailable
```

Now the app needs to update the current screen when Airplay devices become available, is there a way to do that?

EDIT: This notification seems to be deprecated, is there any replacement? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeviewwirelessrouteactivedidchangenotification?language=objc#discussion

Comment: I've now come across MPVolumeViewWirelessRoutesAvailableDidChangeNotification, I have no way to test it right now, can someone confirm this will be sent when Airplay devices are recognised and lost?

Comment: The audio session notifies you any time routing changes.

Comment: Thank you Matt, are you referring to a notification distributed by AVAudioSession? I thought I could just add an observer and update .showsRouteButton as done in the ViewWillAppear(), but what need I to observe?